# Regex won't match basic url when the ?id=$1 is added

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with regular expressions. I've been trying to get a very basic url re-route working from:

```
..myDomain/ecommerceWebsite/products/index.php?id=101
```

to:

```
..myDomain/ecommerceWebsite/products/101
```

I have written this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule products/index.php?id=$1 ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ [L]
```

The re-route works until I add the `?id=$1` part, then it just seems to ignore the rule. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Apache's Rewrite rules, but a `$` in regex usually marks the end of a line. You probably want something like `\?id=(\d+)$` as regex (`?` is also a special character so should be escaped), and refer to the captured group with `$1` in your replacement. I quickly peeked [at mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll take a look at those docs and escaping characters

Answer (score 0):

This should work and silently change `ecommerceWebsite/products/index.php?id=101` to `ecommerceWebsite/products/101`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /ecommerceWebsite/products/index\.php\?id=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /ecommerceWebsite/products/%2\? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Mmm unfortunately that just gave me an internal server error. Regex just don't seem to want to work for me:(

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark it as correct so other people with the same question as you will know how you solved it.